# PDF image in PDF document using ReportLab (Python)

Tags: python, image, pdf, reportlab

I saved some plots from matplotlib into a pdf format because it seems to offer better quality. How do I include the PDF image into a PDF document using ReportLab? The convenience method `Image(filename)` does not work for this format.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the wonderful pdfrw package together with reportlab and use it to pass file-like objects of matplotlib figures directly into a flowable:

This was answered before, but I want to give a minimal example here, please also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870512/4497962

```
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfDict
from pdfrw.buildxobj import pagexobj
from pdfrw.toreportlab import makerl
from reportlab.platypus import Flowable
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY,TA_LEFT,TA_CENTER,TA_RIGHT

class PdfImage(Flowable):
    """
    PdfImage wraps the first page from a PDF file as a Flowable
    which can be included into a ReportLab Platypus document.
    Based on the vectorpdf extension in rst2pdf (http://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/)

    This can be used from the place where you want to return your matplotlib image
    as a Flowable:

        img = BytesIO()

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(canvaswidth,canvaswidth))

        ax.plot([1,2,3],[6,5,4],antialiased=True,linewidth=2,color='red',label='a curve')

        fig.savefig(img,format='PDF')

        return(PdfImage(img))

    """

    def __init__(self, filename_or_object, width=None, height=None, kind='direct'):
        # If using StringIO buffer, set pointer to begining
        if hasattr(filename_or_object, 'read'):
            filename_or_object.seek(0)
            #print("read")
        self.page = PdfReader(filename_or_object, decompress=False).pages[0]
        self.xobj = pagexobj(self.page)

        self.imageWidth = width
        self.imageHeight = height
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.xobj.BBox

        self._w, self._h = x2 - x1, y2 - y1
        if not self.imageWidth:
            self.imageWidth = self._w
        if not self.imageHeight:
            self.imageHeight = self._h
        self.__ratio = float(self.imageWidth)/self.imageHeight
        if kind in ['direct','absolute'] or width==None or height==None:
            self.drawWidth = width or self.imageWidth
            self.drawHeight = height or self.imageHeight
        elif kind in ['bound','proportional']:
            factor = min(float(width)/self._w,float(height)/self._h)
            self.drawWidth = self._w*factor
            self.drawHeight = self._h*factor

    def wrap(self, availableWidth, availableHeight):
        """
        returns draw- width and height

        convenience function to adapt your image 
        to the available Space that is available
        """
        return self.drawWidth, self.drawHeight

    def drawOn(self, canv, x, y, _sW=0):
        """
        translates Bounding Box and scales the given canvas
        """
        if _sW > 0 and hasattr(self, 'hAlign'):
            a = self.hAlign
            if a in ('CENTER', 'CENTRE', TA_CENTER):
                x += 0.5*_sW
            elif a in ('RIGHT', TA_RIGHT):
                x += _sW
            elif a not in ('LEFT', TA_LEFT):
                raise ValueError("Bad hAlign value " + str(a))

        #xobj_name = makerl(canv._doc, self.xobj)
        xobj_name = makerl(canv, self.xobj)

        xscale = self.drawWidth/self._w
        yscale = self.drawHeight/self._h

        x -= self.xobj.BBox[0] * xscale
        y -= self.xobj.BBox[1] * yscale

        canv.saveState()
        canv.translate(x, y)
        canv.scale(xscale, yscale)
        canv.doForm(xobj_name)
        canv.restoreState()
```

Comment: It is exactly what I needed! Thank you a lot for the code!

Comment: If you liked this you might also want to take a look at this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobasedoc/

Comment: Thanks for the code! I'm having some trouble while trying to set the position of an image with the method drawOn What should I pass to its first argument?

Comment: Ola Murilo, tudo bem? It's the canvas object: image.drawOn(canv, x, y), see reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py in class Canvas

Answer (score 2):

According to [ReportLab's FAQ](https://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/faq/#2.1.6) this is only possible with ReportLab PLUS:

> Can I use vector graphics in my PDFs?
>
> No, the Open Source package doesn't do
>   this. PageCatcher (see the previous
>   answer) allows you to easily
>   incorporate any vector image by saving
>   it as a PDF and then using it exactly
>   as you would an image file, and Report
>   Markup Language accepts PDF files
>   along with JPG, GIF and PNG.

**Update**: I haven't looked into this for a while but [on the page of pdfrw](https://code.google.com/p/pdfrw/) it says:

> pdfrw can read and write PDF files, and can also be used to read in PDFs which can then be used inside reportlab.

Comment: That is correct.  There are a couple of examples using pdfrw for this both at the pdfrw page, and in some [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712386/loading-matplotlib-object-into-reportlab/) here

Comment: If you can take the vector data itself, you can draw on a reportlab canvas.  That produces beautiful graphics without images

Comment: this answer is not correct, see my answer from Jan 23 '17

Answer (score 0):

You can use **svg** export from matplotlib and use `svglib` python library to include vector graphics in reportlab generated PDF files. `svglib` takes a svg file and makes a drawing object that can be directly used in reportlab.

See also this question for more details: [Generating PDFs from SVG input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835795/generating-pdfs-from-svg-input)

Comment: the above is the preferred way, as you don't have to file operations on the storage, and by the way, svglib uses pdfrw...

Answer (score -5):

Use from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

Comment: This is incorrect. renderPDF takes the EXISTING document and generates a PDF. The exact opposite of what the poster wants.