# Using reportlab to build PDF with vector-based graphs generated by matplotlib

Tags: svg, matplotlib, reportlab

I'm trying to build PDF-documents on the server-side in a Django-Installation using [reportlab](http://reportlab.com). These documents should contain several graphs which are to be created with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net).

I already figured out how to make reportlab use matplotlib's images without dumping them to the filesystem temporarily by passing [PIL-Image objects](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) directly to the `Image()`-flowable. This works surprisingly well for rasterized images formats like PNG.

Now, the icing on the cake would be able to embed vector based graphics (like SVG).

I used [svglib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/) to convert SVGs generated by matplotlib to reportlab graphic objects but unfortunately svglib does omit the tickmarks and axis labels. On some graphs it fails in general.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: In my experience matplotlib is kind of buggy.  It's likely because they are doing something weird.  You might try filing a bug report with them.

Answer (score 6):

This page has a solution that I haven't had a chance to test myself yet: https://web.archive.org/web/20120725125858/http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/weblog/posts/BB753.html

Answer (score 2):

You can generate matplotlib graphics as pdf and use [pdfrw](http://code.google.com/p/pdfrw/) to embed it in reportlab canvas as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870512/1332370)