# Matplotlib figure to PDF without saving

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, reportlab

I have to create a group of matplotlib figures, which I would like to directly present in a PDF report without saving them as a file.

The data for my plots is stored in a Pandas DataFrame:

Right now I do not know other better option than first save the image and use it later.

I am doing something like that:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Image

for index, row in myDataFrame.iterrows():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(row['Xvalues'], row['Yvalues'],'o', color='r')
    fig.savefig('figure_%s.png' % (row['ID']))
    plt.close(fig)

text = []
doc = BaseDocTemplate(pageName, pagesize=landscape(A4))

for f in listdir(myFolder):
    if f.endswith('png'):
        image1 = Image(f)
        text.append(image1)

doc.build(text)
```

Comment: my work flow now is like that: 1. create a bunch of figures 2. save the figures as .png 3. send the .png figures to the PDF So the question is if I can skip step 2 and go from creating the figures to present them on the PDF

Comment: You might be able to use a memory-mapped file for this, but I'm not sure if Matplotlib and Platypus support these: https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best solution provided by matplotlib itself:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with PdfPages('foo.pdf') as pdf:
    #As many times as you like, create a figure fig and save it:
    fig = plt.figure()
    pdf.savefig(fig)

    ....
    fig = plt.figure()
    pdf.savefig(fig)
```

Voilà

Find a full example here: [multipage pdf matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html)

Comment: sry to say, but that is not the best solution, as you say, but maybe it's among the shortest and also very good, but pay more attention next time, the question was: "to directly present in a PDF report" a report involves much more than just matplotlib, you want tables, paragraphs, hyphenation, coherent font types, etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you can save the figure into a buffer using `io.BytessIO` and use that in platypus. Something like this perhaps?

```
import io
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Image

buffers = []

for index, row in myDataFrame.iterrows():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(row['Xvalues'], row['Yvalues'],'o', color='r')

    mybuffer = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(mybuffer, format = 'pdf')
    mybuffer.seek(0)
    buffers.append(mybuffer)
    plt.close(fig)

text = []
doc = BaseDocTemplate(pageName, pagesize=landscape(A4))

doc.build(buffers)
```

Answer (score 0):

using my package autobasedoc https://pypi.org/project/autobasedoc/ your example would look like that:

```
from autobasedoc import autorpt as ar
from autobasedoc import autoplot as ap

@ap.autoPdfImg
def my_plot(index, row, canvaswidth=5): #[inch]
    fig, ax = ap.plt.subplots(figsize=(canvaswidth,canvaswidth))
    fig.suptitle(f"My simple plot {index}", fontproperties=fontprop)
    ax.plot(row['Xvalues'], row['Yvalues'],label=f"legendlabel{index}")
    return fig

doc = ar.AutoDocTemplate(pageName)

content = []

for index, row in myDataFrame.iterrows():
    content.append(my_plot(index, row))

doc.build(content)
```