# Multiple matplotlib plots in reportlab

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, reportlab

I'm trying to put a matplotlib graph onto a reportlab canvas. I can do a simple graph with the code from this question: [How to drawImage a matplotlib figure in a reportlab canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897511/how-to-drawimage-a-matplotlib-figure-in-a-reportlab-canvas)
But when I try to use subplots or use multiple plots it will not work properly. Doing it this way causes the same image to be plotted twice even when I added things like imgdata.close() or deleting the figure:

```
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import cStringIO
    from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
    from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader       

    can = canvas.Canvas()
    self.f = Figure()
    plot(x,y)
    xlabel(xlbl)
    ylabel(ylbl)

    imgdata=cStringIO.StringIO()
    savefig(imgdata,format='png')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    Image = ImageReader(imgdata)
    can.drawImage(Image,100,250, width=400,height=350)

    self.g = Figure()
    plot(x,y)
    xlabel(xlbl)
    ylabel(ylbl)

    secondimgdata = cStringIO.StringIO()
    savefig(secondimgdata,format='png')
    secondimgdata.seek(0)

    Image2 = ImageReader(secondimgdata)
    can.drawImage(Image2,100,150, width=400,height=350)
```

When trying with subplots it simply produces a blank graph and I did not know where to go with it:

```
    self.f = Figure()
    self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
    self.a.plot(x,y)
    self.a2 =self.a.twinx()
    self.a2.plot(x,y2,'r')
    self.a2.set_ylabel(ylbl2)
    self.a.set_xlabel(xlbl)
    self.a.set_ylabel(ylbl)
```

Any solution or advice to this problem would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an ideal solution as it has to save the file as an image instead of using StringIO but it works.

```
    import Image as image
    from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
    from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
    from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader

    can = canvas.Canvas()
    self.f = figure()
    self.a = self.f.add_subplot(2,1,1)
    self.a.plot(x,y)
    self.a2 =self.a.twinx()
    self.a2.plot(x,y2,'r')
    self.a2.set_ylabel(ylbl2,color='r')
    self.a.set_xlabel(xlbl)
    self.a.set_ylabel(ylbl,color='b')


    self.f.savefig('plot.png',format='png')
    image.open('plot.png').save('plot.png','PNG')   
    can.drawImage('plot.png',100,250, width=400,height=350)
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is that you must use `plt.close()` after you're done adding images.  Here's a quick example that works for me using seaborn and barplot.  Assume I have a dataframe with different data that I want plotted over a few figures.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import cStringIO
from reportlab.platypus import Image

my_df = <some dataframe>
cols_to_plot = <[specific columns to plot]>

plots = []

def create_barplot(col):
    sns_plot = sns.barplot(x='col1', y=col, hue='col2', data=my_df)
    imgdata = cStringIO.StringIO()
    sns_plot.figure.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
    imgdata.seek(0)
    plots.append(Image(imgdata))
    plt.close()                   # This is the key!!!

for col in cols_to_plot:
    create_barplot(col)

for barplot in plots:
    story.append(barplot)
```

Comment: Thanks for this...Blue skies