# Using np.array on Reportlab, Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, reportlab

I am doing a script to generate a report on PDF after some image analysis, the problem is that reading the examples of reportlab they load an image by filename and then generate it on the report, but I have the image as a `np.array` and don't want to save it because there will be a lot of images, and when I tried to do this reportlab command

```
#asd is the image variable
asd=plt.imread(imagen_fl)
#then do some image processing.... 
canvas.drawImage(asd, 1*cm, 3*cm, 10*cm, 10*cm )
```

I get the next error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Any solution or recomendation?

Comment: Ivan, your question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897511/how-to-drawimage-a-matplotlib-figure-in-a-reportlab-canvas

Comment: Also, take another look at the [documentation for `canvas.drawImage`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas.drawImage), and note that the function does not accept numpy arrays as the first argument.