# Write a matplotlib figure to a ReportLab PDF file without saving image to disk

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I'm trying to find a way to write a matplotlib figure to a PDF via reportlab (4.0.6 open-source version). According to its [doc](https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch2_graphics/#image-methods), it should accept a PIL Image object, but I tried the following and it returned `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Image`.

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvas

c = canvas.Canvas('test-pdf.pdf')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 4], [3, 4, 6], '-o')
fig_canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
fig_canvas.draw()
img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(fig_canvas.buffer_rgba()))

c.drawImage(img, 0, 0)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

I have seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897511/how-to-drawimage-a-matplotlib-figure-in-a-reportlab-canvas), but it's very old and uses other dependencies. Is there a way to achieve this just using PIL or numpy or any python3 first-party packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a file-like object. First we use the method `plt.savefig` to write and the method `reportlab` `ImageReader` to read from it.

```
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = canvas.Canvas('test-pdf.pdf')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 4], [3, 4, 6], '-o')

b = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(b, format='png')

image = ImageReader(b)
c.drawImage(image, 0, 0)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Comment: Thank you. May I know why a savefig must happen? We can't convert a fig to a readable format to drawImage directly?

Comment: @steven I tried various ways. Everywhere you had to either open the file or write it to disk. You can write directly from `matplotlib` to `PDF` using `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf`. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_pdf_api.html.

Comment: Indeed, it's kind of weird.