# How to place graphics created by matplotlib on the fly into rml template?

Tags: python, matplotlib, reportlab, rml

I have a question about how to place  graphics created by matplotlib on the fly into rml template. The key maybe related to which tag I should use. Larry Meyn's https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870512/1046012 solution is good for including such graph into SimpledocTemplate (Great job.Thanks.) However, it seems not suitable for rml template. Does anyone know if there is a workaround. Thanks.