# Creating an infographic with multiple PDF's in Python

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, reportlab

I've created multiple charts using Matplotlib and saved them as PDF's. I need to combine up to 5 PDF's into one PDF, as this will be done many times the task needs to automated with Python. The reason I'm combining PDF's instead of .jpg or .png is that the PDF scales the best and doesn't result in a fuzzy image. I've tried using code from here [Is there a matplotlib flowable for ReportLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690585/is-there-a-matplotlib-flowable-for-reportlab) but I don't understand how to control the image placement. Reportlab has a function:
`.drawImage(file, x-coord, y-coord)` which allows for specific placement of the image on the page, unfortunately this function only takes .jpg or .png which are too low quality. If anyone has any suggestions on how to combine PDF's it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You already said why you'd prefer PDF, but still I think you should look at increasing the resolution of those .pngs. It is not likely that you'll find it easy to write something that makes a 2D graphics array of pdfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this I've found that the best way to actually do this is in Latex. There is a python plugin called PyLatex but there is no documentation so instead I will create a Latex template then using subprocess.call in my Python script create the Infographic.