# Generating PDFs from SVG input

Tags: python, django, pdf, svg

I am trying to generate a PDF from a SVG input file with Python in a Django application.

I have already found 2 working solutions: cairo+rsvg and imagemagick but they both have one problem: They have some strange dependencies that I do not want to install on a server, for example DBUS and GTK.

So I am asking for another method for generating a PDF from SVG without having to install all these dependencies on a server.

Comment: This is EXACTLY my problem, but I have another limitation: being Unicode-compatible (for non-english texts inside svg).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have you considered [svglib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/)?

It looks quite promising, especially as reportlab is the [featured pdf tool](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/#install-reportlab) in Django's docs.

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

drawing = svg2rlg("file.svg")
renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "file.pdf")
```

Comment: hmmm, this library is good, but seems that has problems with non-ascii (unicode) text!  
I'm still searching for a unicode-compatible library...

Comment: how to add multiple drawings to one PDF?

Comment: Just a side note to people... Make sure your .svg is formatted correctly... for some reason mine was formatted as a string... which mean that any occurrence of " or ' in the file was written with a \" or \'... That will cause issues...

Answer (score 18):

Yes, I would also suggest using [svglib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/) and the [reportlab library](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/dev/graphics.html#module-reportlab.graphics.renderPDF) for this task although there is very little documentation of the svglib library. I would actually suggest doing the following in your Django view:

```
from svglib.svglib import SvgRenderer
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
import xml.dom.minidom
@csrf_exempt
def export_svg(request):
    # Get data from client side via POST variables
    svg = request.POST.get("svg")
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(svg.encode( "utf-8" ))
    svg = doc.documentElement
    # Create new instance of SvgRenderer class
    svgRenderer = SvgRenderer()
    svgRenderer.render(svg)
    drawing = svgRenderer.finish()

    # Instead of outputting to a file, we simple return
    # the data and let the user download to their machine
    pdf = renderPDF.drawToString(drawing)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response.write(pdf)     

    # If one were to remove the 'attachment; ' from this line
    # it would simple invoke the browsers default PDF plugin
    response["Content-Disposition"]= "attachment; filename=converted.pdf"
    return response
```

This way you never need to save a temporary file on the server for the user to just download locally anyway. The svglib example that is given requires providing a path to a file... but why not just provide the file itself?

I have documented the steps I have taken using Django and the Raphael SVG library [here](http://alexandersimoes.com/journal/2011/07/12/convert-svg-to-pdf-and-prompt-for-download/).

Comment: The HttpResponse object is a file-like object so you can directly write the PDF to it.

Comment: Seems link is broken. It goes to a default page.

Answer (score 8):

My answer may help someone on macOS:

I user [CairoSVG](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG)

Firstly, install it with:

```
pip install cairosvg
```

Then you can use it in Python:

```
>>> import cairosvg
>>> cairosvg.svg2pdf(url='image.svg', write_to='image.pdf')
```

from its [documentation](https://cairosvg.org/documentation/):

> on macOS, you’ll have to install `cairo` and `libffi` (with Homebrew for example)

Comment: Note for M1/M2 chip users: this might not work! I tried for hours and I couldn't get `cairosvg` to be imported correctly. The error message was `"cairosvg" is not accessed Pylance`.

Comment: For getting this to work on Windows see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77712749/1725562

Answer (score 2):

As these answers are all quite old, I would like to post a modern solution using [CairoSVG](https://cairosvg.org/)

This works with Django views:

```
import cairosvg

def export_svg(request):
    # Get data from POST
    svg = request.POST.get("svg")
    pdf = cairosvg.svg2pdf(bytestring=svg.encode("utf-8"))

    # The pdf is now a bytestring that can be returned instead of saving to disk. 
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response.write(pdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add "import string" for version 0.6.3 to work with python 2.7.

you can use my frok until the pypy is updated.

```
pip install git+git://github.com/ddehghan/libsvg.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally use `pdfkit` wrapper for `Wkhtmltopdf`.
I tested with your example of SVG and it does have opacity.

Though, to test - I've enclosed SVG file into HTML and then converted HTML to PDF.

You can give it a try on my server (which uses `Wkhtmltopdf`):

```
response = requests.post('http://194.67.110.124:8000/html_to_pdf/',
                         files={
                             'template': ('template.html', open('template.html', 'rb')),
                             'picture': ('template.svg', open('template.svg', 'rb'))
                         },
                         data={})
```

where **template.html** is an HTML file contained SVG with prefix `{{image_path}}`. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<img src="{{image_path}}/template.svg">
</html>
```

and `template.svg` if the SVG file. The result I get is:

[image]

The code for pdfkit is quite simple:

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_file('template.html', 'output.pdf')
```

Where `template.html` contains the embedded SVG.

Note that `pdfkit` is only a wrapper and `Wkhtmltopdf` app has to be installed on the machine. (BTW, on Windows it's quite slow)

Comment: @KJ on Windows it's ridiculously slow anyway, much better even to run it inside Docker container under Windows. 
Regarding the command - I see that it initiates Wkhtmltopdf process as `Wkhtmltopdf - out.pdf` and then passes the HTML file as UTF-8 text into stdin of the process.

Comment: @KJ When running on windows I also don't see the SVG. You can check the source of my server here: https://github.com/Luckykarter/html_to_pdf/blob/main/html_to_pdf/views.py and play around locally