# Python convert SVGz to PDF: no response

Tags: python-3.x, svg

I tried  to convert a batch of `.svgz` into a single pdf file following the instructions of [Generating PDFs from SVG input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835795/generating-pdfs-from-svg-input).

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

renderPDF.drawToFile(svg2rlg("images/p1.svgz"), "out.pdf")
```

Encounter the issue `OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'<s')`. The file is not compressed at all as I can read the file with `cat`.

I changed the filename extension to `.svg` with `mv`, run again the above codes `renderPDF.drawToFile(svg2rlg("images_svg/p1.svg"), "out.pdf")`, but got nothing response.

I terminated the process with `Ctrl` + `c`, and got this,

```
$ python3 img_to_pdf.py 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 658, in open_for_read
    return open_for_read_by_name(name,mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 602, in open_for_read_by_name
    return open(name,mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'p2_g_d0_f57.ttf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/lib/utils.py", line 661, in open_for_read
    return getBytesIO(datareader(name) if name[:5].lower()=='data:' else urlopen(name).read())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 510, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'p2_g_d0_f57.ttf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
......
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: z is just a letter in the filename, it ought to be used to indicate the file is compressed but it doesn't guarantee it.