# Opacity issue when saving a SVG in a PDF with Reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, svg, opacity, reportlab

I have this SVG file:

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 390 390" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <line class="arrow" opacity="0.5" stroke="#15781B" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="9.0" x1="307.5" x2="279.60592002787337" y1="352.5" y2="296.7118400557468" />
    <polygon class="arrow" fill="#15781B" opacity="0.5019607843137255" points="264.51246117974983,266.5249223594996 264.5124611797498,304.25856947980856 294.69937887599696,289.165110631685" />
    <text fill="white" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" opacity="0.5" x="264.0" y="291.0">DEF</text>
    <line class="arrow" opacity="0.5019607843137255" stroke="#15781B" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="9.0" x1="262.5" x2="262.5" y1="307.5" y2="255.75" />
    <polygon class="arrow" fill="#15781B" opacity="0.5" points="262.5,222.0 245.625,255.75 279.375,255.75" />
    <text fill="white"  font-size="11" font-weight="bold" opacity="0.5" x="252.0" y="249.0">ABC</text>
</svg>
```

If you save it as a `b.svg` file, and open it, you will see that there is some overlapping with opacity : the text `ABC` and `DEF` **is readable**.

Now when I render it in a PDF file with the well-known method from [Generating PDFs from SVG input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835795/generating-pdfs-from-svg-input/5835909#5835909) :

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
drawing = svg2rlg("b.svg")
renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "b.pdf")
```

then the opacity is lost in the PDF file, and the left part of the D letter of "DEF" is unreadable:

[image]

**Question: How to include a SVG into a PDF and keep the opacity?**

Comment: @KJ How can we check this?

Comment: @KJ Then, how to change this code to allow this transparency to be displayed by most readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the svglib code shows that svglib does not parse the "opacity" attribute, but it does parse the "fill-opacity" and "stroke-opacity" attributes. So changing your svg to

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 390 390" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <line class="arrow" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke="#15781B" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="9.0" x1="307.5" x2="279.60592002787337" y1="352.5" y2="296.7118400557468" />
    <polygon class="arrow" fill="#15781B" fill-opacity="0.5019607843137255" stroke-opacity="0.5019607843137255" points="264.51246117974983,266.5249223594996 264.5124611797498,304.25856947980856 294.69937887599696,289.165110631685" />
    <text fill="white" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" x="264.0" y="291.0">DEF</text>
    <line class="arrow" fill-opacity="0.5019607843137255" stroke-opacity="0.5019607843137255" stroke="#15781B" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="9.0" x1="262.5" x2="262.5" y1="307.5" y2="255.75" />
    <polygon class="arrow" fill="#15781B" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" points="262.5,222.0 245.625,255.75 279.375,255.75" />
    <text fill="white"  font-size="11" font-weight="bold" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" x="252.0" y="249.0">ABC</text>
</svg>
```

should do the trick.
[image]

**UPDATE**

This seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/109) since 2018

Answer (score 0):

To long for a comment and the Kudos / **Bonus should go to @zap** for pointing me at rebuilding all the shapes to Polygons which worked significantly better than Rect.

I still **struggle** to understand twice so as to get WkHtmlToPDF to give me a good ***scalar*** PDF but it did give me transparency with the following.

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 390 390" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polygon class="arrow" fill="#15781B" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" points="275.75,298.6 283.6,294.6 312,350.5 303.5,354.5" />
    <polygon class="arrow" fill="#15781B" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" points="264.5125,266.5249 264.5125,304.25856 294.6994,289.1651" />
    <text fill="white" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" x="264.0" y="291.0">DEF</text>
    <polygon class="arrow" fill="#15781B" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" points="258,255.75 267,255.75 267,307.5 258,307.5" />
    <polygon class="arrow" fill="#15781B" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" points="262.5,222.0 245.625,255.75 279.375,255.75" />
    <text fill="white"  font-size="11" font-weight="bold" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.5" x="250" y="250.0">ABC</text>
</svg>
```

Here are the transparent objects on a transparent background on a snowy day.
Somewhere there must be a means to fix scaling but I did not find it yet and others have said similar.
[image]

The Idea was to keep a minimal as possible approach without any special external adjustments (though I did try many). So the SVG was included as img in an HTML "square" block.

"test1.htm"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    body {background: transparent;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="file:///wkhtmltox\bin\test1.svg" height=390px width=780px />
  </body>
</html>
```

and called directly

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --enable-local-file-access  --disable-smart-shrinking --no-background --no-pdf-compression -n "test1.htm" test1.pdf
```

In the spirit of maintaining opacity I included that aspect in the body style and external --no-background but they normally would not be required
And finally I seem to have got scaling stable so here is the SVG in an A4 transparent page.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you include some code to show how your converted SVG to PDF with WkHtmlToPDF? There are other posts about this but some sample code would still be helpful, some details (about opacity, etc.) might be important here.