# Converting SVG to PDF using CairoSVG fails: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairosvg'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, svg, environment-variables

I need to convert some SVG files to PDF files using Python on Windows 10.

For this purpose I have installed the **CairoSVG** package using the pip command:

> `pip install cairosvg`

It is the latest version (2.7.1) of CairoSVG.

Everything seems to be installed and configured correctly.

A few key details:

- After downloading the latest version of Python (3.12) for my Windows 10 machine (64-bit) I have installed it into the following directory: `D:\Program Files\Python312`.
- The system environment variable PATH has been configured and set to `D:\Program Files\Python312` and `D:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts`.
- I use the latest version of Visual Studio Code for developing Python applications.
- The latest version of the Python extension from the marketplace in Visual Studio Code has been installed.

I tried to run following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835795/generating-pdfs-from-svg-input):

```py
import cairosvg

def export_svg(request):
    # Get data from POST
    svg = request.POST.get("svg")
    pdf = cairosvg.svg2pdf(bytestring=svg.encode("utf-8"))

    # The pdf is now a bytestring that can be returned instead of saving to disk. 
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response.write(pdf)
```

Running this code will result into following error:

```
PS D:\Project WebAuthn> & "D:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/python.exe" c:/Users/USER/Desktop/Python-Projekte/gtk.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python-Projekte\gtk.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cairosvg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairosvg'
```

After trying to reinstall CairoSVG using pip command twice, I got following output in the console:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: cairosvg in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (2.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cairocffi in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from cairosvg) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect2 in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from cairosvg) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from cairosvg) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from cairosvg) (10.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tinycss2 in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from cairosvg) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1.0 in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from cairocffi->cairosvg) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from cssselect2->cairosvg) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from cffi>=1.1.0->cairocffi->cairosvg) (2.21)
```

I am confused. What's wrong? Why can the installed module CairoSVG not be found?

Believe me, I have tried pretty much everything but my problem couldn't be solved.

Help me!

Comment: You're running your script with python at `D:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/python.exe` which is not the one you installed cairosvg with (3.12) and located at `D:\Program Files\Python312`. Try `D:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/python.exe -m pip install cairosvg` or run your script with the proper version.

Comment: I'm just noticing it. Yesterday I have installed Inkscape for other purpose. What does Inkscape have to do with Python in that case? Where is the connection between them?

Comment: Inkscape supports scripting in python https://inkscape.org/~pakin/%E2%98%85simple-inkscape-scripting

Comment: Isn't it unusual that Visual Studio Code automatically tries to bind the Inkscape directory to run a Python script? I didn't set that up. Why is that so?

Comment: You must have chosen this interpreter at some point (maybe inadvertently) see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/docs/python/environments.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Python extension to execute the code and choose the correct interpreter for it (*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`*). The current interpreter version will be displayed in the lower right corner, and you can also switch by clicking it.

***Switch to the interpreter installed with the `cairosvg` package.***

As far as your problem is concerned, your **cairosvg** is installed in `c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages`,

[image]

But the interpreter you currently use is `D:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/python.exe`.

[image]

##### There are two solutions:

1. Switch the interpreter to `c:\users\USER\appdata\roaming\python\python312`.
2. Install the **cairosvg** package for the current Python environment (*`D:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/python.exe`*).