# PDF images unscaled to PDF document using pdfrw/ReportLab

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab, pdfrw

This question is very similar to [PDF image in PDF document using ReportLab (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448365/pdf-image-in-pdf-document-using-reportlab-python), but I seem unable to adapt it to my needs:

I want to add vectorized images (available in SVG oder PDF format) to an A4 PDF output. The images must not get scaled! They should simply be placed from top to bottom with some vertical spacing and automatic page breaks.

No text or other content is required. Basically, I'm looking for a pdfnup solution. In the past, I have used pdflatex with a simple input file for the task, but this is no option for the target system.

Comment: Would the PdfPages backend of matplotlib be an option for you? https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html

Comment: Interesting, this seems to be very straight forward! How can I save existing PDF graphics to the new PDF page?