# Turn `matplotlib.pyplot` plot into `Flowable` object to embed in ReportLab PDF without external libraries

Tags: python, matplotlib, reportlab

Is there a way to turn a `matplotlib.pyplot` plot into a `Flowable` object within `reportlab` so that I can render it within a pdf?

My question is very similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690585/is-there-a-matplotlib-flowable-for-reportlab).  However, I am limited because I am working on a system where I can only use a certain set of libraries.  These are:

- The libraries installed with [Anaconda 2](https://conda.io/docs/download.html)
- `reportlab`

Is this possible with the set of packages that I have?

EDIT: I would like to avoid saving the plot as a png

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448365/pdf-image-in-pdf-document-using-reportlab-python According to one of the answers, the free version of reportlab does not allow to include pdf directly, hence available solutions take the detour using `pdfrw`.

Comment: The better solution is of course to use [`svglib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/) as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835795/generating-pdfs-from-svg-input).